# replace first whitespace until last whitespace after comma only within parentheses

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

In Notepad++, I would like to replace all references/citations with a citation key.

E.g., the following:

```
Bla bla bla bla (van Author et al., 2015). 
Bla bla bla (Authorone, Authortwo, & Authorthree, 2016). 
Bla bla (Authorone & Authortwo, 2017).
```

Should become:

```
Bla bla bla bla (vanAuthor2015). 
Bla bla bla (Authorone2016). 
Bla bla (Authorone2017).
```

Note that there might also be multiple references in a single line, but there are no nested parentheses.

In a first step I replaced `(?<=\([a-z][a-z][a-z])\s` with nothing to turn the first citation from `(van Author et al., 2015)` into `(vanAuthor et al., 2015)`. This would also work for `(von Author et al., 2015)`.

Explanation:

- `\s` Remove single white space
- `(?<=` that follows
- `\([a-z][a-z][a-z])` an opening parenthesis and 3 lower-case letters.
- `)` close [positive lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/4798582).

However, I am struggling with the 2nd step. **How can I replace the first whitespace until the last whitespace after a comma `\s.*,\s` *only within parentheses***? I read many posts titled "regex only in brackets" but the solutions I came across did not appear to apply to my case.

Comment: Try `(\(\w+)(?:\s+(\w+))?[^)]*\s(\d+\))` --> `$1$2$3`.

Comment: @Wiktor perfect! Do you want to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: Yes, just a sec please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(\(\w+)(?:\s+(\w+))?[^)]*\s(\d+\))
```

and replace with `$1$2$3`.

**Pattern details**:

- `(\(\w+)` - Group 1: a `(`  and then 1+ word chars
- `(?:\s+(\w+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1+ whitespaces and then *capturing* into Group 2 one or more word chars
- `[^)]*` - zero or more chars other than `)`
- `\s` - whitespace
- `(\d+\))` - Group 3: 1+ digits and `)`.

[image]